# How to unit test nested subscribe methods in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

```
MethodToBeTested() {
  this.serviceA.methodA1().subscribe((response) => {
   if (response.Success) {
     this.serviceA.methodA2().subscribe((res) => {
        this.serviceB.methodB1();
      })
    }
  });
}
```

Here is  the scenario.

Things to test:

1. `serviceA.methodA1().` was called.
2. if response.Success then check if `serviceA.methodA2()` was called
3. check if `serviceB.methodB1()` was called when `serviceA.methodA2()` received value.

first, one is easy to test.

```
let spy = spyOn(serviceA, 'methodA1');
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

But does one test 2 and 3?

```
 let spy= spyOn(serviceA, 'methodA1').and.returnValue({subscribe: () => {success:true}});
subject.MethodToBeTested();
```

something like that?

Answer (score 3):

Alright, so I figured out what I am looking for is `callFake`

```
it('should test inside of subscribe', () => {
    let spy = spyOn(serviceA, 'methodA1').and.callFake(() => {
      return of({ success: true });
    });
    let spy2 = spyOn(serviceA, 'methodA2').and.callFake(() => {
      return of({ success: true });
    });
    let spy3 = spyOn(serviceB, 'methodB1').and.returnValue(of({ success: true }));
     subject.MethodToBeTested();
    expect(spy3).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

I learned that `returnValue` won't actually execute the inside of the subscribe while `callFake` will with the data you provide inside it.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to not use a nested subscribe.

Something like this could be a sollution:

```
let $obs1 = this.serviceA.methodA1().pipe(share());
let $obs2 = $obs1.pipe(switchMap(x => this.serviceA.methodA2()));

$obs1.subsribe(logic1 here...);
$obs2.subsribe(logic2 here...);
```

Comment: Let's say, it's somebody else's existing code. And I can't change the code. But I have to write tests.